# Adding a 3d array (ndarray) as displacement for material output in blender python

Tags: python, normal-map, displacement

To the material output node, for the displacement value I wish to add an nd array. Example given below to understand:

```
import numpy as np
nval=np.random.rand(1000,1000,3)
mat=bpy.data.materials["mymaterial"]
nodes=mat.node_tree.nodes
nodes['Material Output'].inputs['Displacement']=nval
```

This obviously throws error at the last step since nval is an ndarray. I know I can add image texure to the displacement map which is 3 dimensional RGB normal map. But I wish to add my own ndarray as displacement map to my material output. How can I do this using python script.

Answer (score 1):

You can only connect a [node output socket](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.NodeSocket.html) to a node input socket, it isn't just an array.

While it is possible to create [custom pynodes](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/Python_Nodes) and be able to add them to a cycles material tree, they aren't fully integrated, mainly they fail to update properly. You can find a [pynode template](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/templates_py/custom_nodes.py) in blender's text editor.  The two main projects using pynodes are [sverchok](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok) and [animation nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes) and you will find both of these use [bpy.app.handlers](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.handlers.html) to update their custom node trees.

You might find [drivers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/drivers/introduction.html) to offer a better solution. It is possible to add custom functions to the [driver namespace](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/drivers/workflow_examples.html#driver-namespace) to give you more control.

You can add a driver to control any value that can be keyframed, right-click <kbd>[image: RMB]</kbd> a value and choose add driver, you can further edit drivers in the [graph editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/graph_editor/introduction.html#mode).

[image: values with drivers]